# div not expanding error

Tags: html, css

im havin this error, in which my div doesnt expand

[image]

the line on top is the div, which is supposed to be surrounding the images and the text that you can see

heres the code:

html

```
    <div class="team sizer">
        <img class="teamtitle" src="FullWeb/v_landingpage/Title.png"/>
        <div class="person1 pimage">
            <img src="FullWeb/v_landingpage/Team_Pic_Base.png"/>
            <p class="ptext">Person 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="person2 pimage">
            <img src="FullWeb/v_landingpage/Team_Pic_Base.png"/>
            <p class="ptext">Person 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="person3 pimage">
            <img src="FullWeb/v_landingpage/Team_Pic_Base.png"/>
            <p class="ptext">Person 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="person4 pimage">
            <img src="FullWeb/v_landingpage/Team_Pic_Base.png"/>
            <p class="ptext">Person 4</p>
        </div>
        <p class="pagebottomtext" width="44.21052631578947%">Lorem ipsum</p
    </div>
```

css:

```
.team{
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.teamtitle{
  position:absolute;
  top:1%;
  left:47.15789473684211%;
  width:5.684210526315789%;
  height:42px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.pimage{
  position:absolute;
  top:120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.person1{
  left:530px;
}

.person2{
  left:770px;
}

.person3{
  left:1010px;
 }

.person4{
  left:1250px;
}

.ptext{
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
  color:#999999;
  font-size:1.1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.pagebottomtext{
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  width:44.21052631578947%;
  top:320px;
  left:27.89473684210527%;
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
  color:#999999;
}
```

thanks in advance for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/UPsew/3/

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net with your code will be more efficient than an image.

Comment: html is also incomplete and cut off ``The Team`` is nowhere to be seen in the sample

Comment: i just forgot to add the </div>, what do you mean by The Team

Comment: Your design is a bit rigid ..here's the same thing a little more responsive: http://jsfiddle.net/UPsew/4/embedded/result/

Comment: if the elements inside the div arent edited by the css the div surrounds them, but if they are it doesnt

Comment: the design is supposed to be rigid and only change when the width is less than 480px

Comment: You don't really need any breakpoints, even float/absolute/relative is superfluous. max-width/inline-block suffice. http://jsfiddle.net/UPsew/10/embedded/result/  resize in your browser, and if you do still need breakpoints, how much of this css will you be overriding vs. all the css you need to override when using absolute positioning ?

Comment: Simplified html/css fully responsive, no float/position/breakpoints http://jsfiddle.net/UPsew/14/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because all the child elements of the `div` have `position: absolute`, and hence are taken out of the flow (i.e. they don't take up any space within the containing `div`, and hence it shrinks to zero height).

You'll need to position them using something else. I had a little play and came up with this using margins to position:

http://jsfiddle.net/UPsew/7/

although you'll probably need to mess with the numbers.

Comment: You beat me to it, i simply redid the html using a float layout so it's a bit more responsive http://jsfiddle.net/UPsew/4/embedded/result/ ..didn't tilt on all the childs being absolute until just now

Comment: :) He/she seemed to be using a fixed width container so figured that using fixed margins was fine. If I were to go all out, I'd probably use a min-width on the container, and percentage margins on the inside.

Comment: but in other parts of the page i did the same and it worked, the div was relative and the child elements were absolute, i want to know why this setup isnt working

Comment: What I said about this setup is right (look up absolute positioning), so if your code elsewhere does something different, then that must be due to something else happening.

Comment: img FullWeb & ptext are not absolute, that's why it seems to work, make them absolute, and you'll have the same border problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow:hidden to the "team" class.

I'm not very sure that's the case, especially that your HTML isn't complete. If this doesn't work, please add your code on jsfiddle.